How many distinct values can cyclotomic polynomials take on (modulo a prime p)?
I have recently been thinking about the following question, which (as far as I know) does not come from any homework or textbook:
Given $\Phi_n(x)$, the $n$th cycltomic polynomial, and a prime $p$, is there a method of telling how many distinct residues the set $\{\Phi_n(0),\Phi_n(1), \dots, \Phi_n(p-1) \}$ contains (modulo $p$)? By method, I mean is there some sort of formula/relation using $n$ and $p$ that gives the number of distinct residues in that set.
For example, when $p = 11$ and $n=10$, the polynomial $\Phi_{10}(x)$ leaves $7$ distinct residues, namely $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9$.
I was unable to make much nontrivial progress on the problem, because when I've computed numerical examples, there doesn't seem to be any consistent pattern, and as far as I know, there might be no such pattern.
I am reasonably familiar with Algebraic Number Theory. Most of the techniques I've used so far are just to try and categorize the $(a, b)$ pairs for which $\Phi_n(a) = \Phi_n(b)$. However, I was not able to get very far with this.
Even for seemingly easy $(n, p)$ pairs, such as $(p-1, p)$, the problem is not obvious to me.
I'm extremely interested in Number Theory, and I'd be interested to know how one might go about solving this.

Side note: $(1, p)$ and $(2, p)$ should be easy and obvious. $(3, p) $ and $(4, p)$ should be doable too, can you add your thoughts in?

Interesting question.  I think the difficulty lies in the fact that while $\Phi_n(x) = 0$ has a clear interpretation in terms of orders, there's no obvious analogue of this for $\Phi_n(x) - c = 0$.

In response to those comments, any cyclotomic polynomial of degree 2 or less should be reasonably easy to check, because for degree 2, one can expect a unique output for each discriminant who is a square mod p, so in this sense, the size of the range of a degree 2 $\Phi_n(x)$ is $\frac{p+1}{2}$. My main reasoning for why this question might have a solution is due to the extremely nice nature of taking the product $\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} \Phi_n(i)$, which frequently evaluates to $\Phi_n(1)$. There are some other cases, but my point is there is that they have some hidden beauty.

This is related to Chebotarev density theorem for function fields, because your question can be translated in the following form: what is the cardinality of the set of $t_0\in \mathbb F_p$ such that $\Phi_n(x)-t_0$ has a root modulo $p$? That is, how many places of degree $1$ in $\mathbb F_p(t)$ have a Frobenius element with at least one fixed point in the Galois closure of the extension of $\mathbb F_p(t)$ generated by the roots of $\Phi_n(x)-t$?

When $n$ is fixed and $p\to \infty$, you should be able to get an asymptotic answer, although perhaps replacing $\mathbb F_p$ with its extension of degree $\varphi(n)$. The answer should be that a positive proportion of $t_0$'s do the job.
